# How the pack() function behave when we explicitly set the location of the container?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, layout-manager

Here is the minimal example what problem I am facing in my main GUI design

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
class GuiTester
{

JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

GuiTester()
{

    JButton newButton = new JButton();
    JButton continueButton = new JButton();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout( panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel.add(newButton);
    panel.add(continueButton);
    panel.add(new JButton());
    panel.add(new JButton());
    panel.add(new JButton());
    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // if I do it here then the display of window is little towards the right side down corner.
    mainFrame.pack();
    //mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null) if I do it here instead of earlier than mainFrame.pack() it works great.
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GuiTester gui = new GuiTester();
  }
}
```

So my question is that how `pack()` working differently when we do `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` prior to it and later to it?

And if we do `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` after `pack()` it works good.

Although the difference in this minimal example is not huge but in my actual working GUI this is creating a huge problem. Please explain.

**EDIT** My second question is that I have heard that it is recommended to call `setVisible(true)` or `setReiszable(false)` prior to pack(), why it is so?

Comment: See also [How to best position Swing GUIs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7143287/418556) in which the exact another different GUI positioning philosophy takes over.

Comment: *"..have heard that it is recommended to call `setVisible(true)` or `setReiszable(false)` prior to `pack()`"*  True for the 2nd, false for the 1st.  But please limit each thread to one (specific) question.  In this case, I feel that the 1st specific question has been [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31822168/418556).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setLocationRelativeTo` uses the current size of the window to make decisions about where it should be placed, since the window hasn't been sized yet, it's using `0x0`, `pack` provides the initial size, so calling this first provides `setLocationRelativeTo` with the information it needs

You have to recognize that until a component is laid out (or in the case, until the is window packed or sized) it has no size.

For example...

```
mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
mainFrame.pack();
```

This says, position the window, which is sized `0x0` to the center point of the screen, then use `pack` to provide an actual size

Where as...

```
mainFrame.pack();
mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Says, `pack` the frame to provide it with an initial size and the position it relative to the center of the screen, which takes into consideration windows size as calculated by `pack`

Comment: I have also heard that we should call setVisible(true) or setResizable prior to pack, why it is so?

Comment: Actually, you should call `pack` before `setVisible`, or more to the point, call `setVisible` last.  The point here is if you make the window visible first and then call `pack`, it can appear on the screen unpacked and the suddenly "pop" to the packed size, which is not a great user experience.  You should call `setResizable` before `pack` because this can change the frame borders of the windows and can produce undesirable margins around the content.  So, use `setResizable`, `pack`, `setVisible` in that order as a general rule of thumb ;)

Comment: Please have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595897/why-is-calling-jframe-pack-adding-extra-space

Comment: The accepted answer on that question (which is correct info.) is *"Make sure to call `setResizable(false)` before calling `pack()` or `setVisible(true)`"* .. Although it does not explicitly state that `setVisible(true)` should be called *last,* it is *implied* by the order of the method calls in that sentence.

Comment: @AndrewThompson oh I misinterpreted that sorry

Comment: No problem.  Glad I could help clarify it.  :)

Comment: But OK.. just to clear any remaining doubts.  The reason to call `setResizable(false)` before `pack()` is that the window 'chrome' (decorations around the edges of the window) might change between resizable and non resizable modes.  By packing the window *after* the resizable property is set, the API will account for the (typically thinner) chrome used for a non-resizable window.

Comment: @AndrewThompson But how 'chrome' changes between resizable and non resizable modes?